# Select a photo from the gallery and show it in another Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, android-studio

I am making an mobile app in which i have to select image from gallery by clicking a button and then display it in another activity. The problem is the image wont show to the second activity. Theres no problems running the code. what would be the problem.. PLEASE HELP ME

```
MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void buttonGalleryOpen(View view)
{
Intent intent = new         Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    //noinspection deprecation
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
Bitmap selectedphoto = null;


super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){

Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String [] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null,     null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
selectedphoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
 cursor.close();
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,gallery_view.class);
intent.putExtra("data", selectedphoto);
startActivity(intent);
}
}
}
```

I am making an mobile app in which i have to select image from gallery by clicking a button and then display it in another activity. The problem is the image wont show to the second activity. Theres no problems running the code. what would be the problem.. PLEASE HELP ME

```
This is an activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textview1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="camera sample"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"
android:layout_marginTop="3dp">

<Button
android:id="@+id/bottonGalleryOpen"
android:onClick="buttonGalleryOpen"

android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="pick" />

</RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

gallery_view.java

```
public class gallery_view extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery_view);
ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageShow);
Bitmap selectedImage  =(Bitmap)this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("data");
imageview.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);

}
}
```

gallery_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relative_1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center">

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="camera sample"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_below="@id/relative_1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/ImageShow"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="500dp" />
    
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You are putting a bitmap in an extra for an intent. Are you getting it out by =(Bitmap)this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("data") ? Or do you get null?

Comment: For the rest its a bad idea to put a bitmap in an extra. When even possible.. The bitmap takes more memory then the file itself so you could better put the file in the intent if it were possible. Also a bad idea.

Comment: Better transfer uri.toString() to the next activity and let it load the file itself.

Comment: it redericted to the first activity. Need some help here

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand what you said. And i see no new code where you only try to transfer uri.toString().

Answer (score 0):

This line in your code does not make sense:

```
intent.putExtra("data", "selectedphoto");
```

You are adding here string "selectedphoto" which is in no way connected to selectedphoto variable you initialised earlier. You could put your bitmap to intent extra as byte array but this is in-efficient, especially when the image is large.
Instead of passing bitmap to ShowImage activity, pass your URI and then retrieve actual bitmap in ShowImage activity exactly as you do now in your PictureOptions activity.

```
intent.setData(passed uri here);
```

In your ShowImage activity do:

```
URI imageUri = getIntent().getData();
```

Comment: `exactly as you do now in ..` Well i would not advertise that bad code. Did you try something like this yourself?

Comment: Further: your intention is good but it cannot work as long as you use ACTION_GET_CONTENT. Please try all yourself first.